# Can someone please explain how paths work in PHP include() situations

Tags: php

I don't get it. 
When trying to include files from different directories, i'm sure i must be missing something real simple.

Site structure is like this. 
[image: Directory Structure]

if i `include("includes/header.php);` from inside the /reports/top_sellers_report.php file, the call to the css file doesn't work. 
To make it work i must put `../styles/styles.css` 
But then, if i open "product_dtails.php from the root, it too includes the header, and then the css file won't load and i need to remove the `../` to make it work. 
I can't win... 
 
Am i missing something? 
4 hours of searching online suggests i am!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not really PHP-related. Just look at the URLs:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/reports/
http://www.example.com/styles/styles.css
```

Depending on where you are on your site, the relative path to `styles.css` might change, thus when you access `http://www.example.com/reports/` you have to use `../styles/styles.css`, wheras in `http://www.example.com/` you have to us `styles/styles.css`.

Probably the easiest way to fix your problem is either by using the absolute URL like `http://www.example.com/styles/styles.css` or the base-path `/styles/styles.css` instead of `../styles/styles.css`. I recommend the latter.

Comment: this is definitely helping. just wondering how to use the base-path method. I tried adding the /styles but it's not working. i tried `<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; $path .= "admin/" ; ?>` doesn't seem to work either. it's driving me nuts!

Comment: You could try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and replace folders with `..`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into using an MVC approach as this would probably help you organise your code better:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

The include statements are evaluated on the server, so wherever you are including the file from, you need to specify it relatively from there. The CSS 'include' is being evaluated in the browser, so you need to make the file path relative from that directory.

I suggested looking to the MVC approach as it helps you to manage your code and separate the different parts of your website into distinct parts which should help you avoid this issue.

I suppose you can refer to you stylesheet absolutely though (ie http://www.mywebsite.com/dir/dir2/stylesheet.css) on each page and that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, include is relative to your index so you have root/index.php

within index.php you should use include("styles/style.css")
within includes/header.php you'll need to add the ../styles to redirect you to root and then to your styles folder and so on

if you open directly product_dtails.php it will act like the index.php, so you need to just use styles/style.php